# Has someone set up an HP DeskJet 812C with SnowLeopard or Lion?

Tags: macos, printing

My parents have an old printer: an HP DeskJet 812C. I upgraded the OS on their iMac to SnowLeopard before checking if the printer was compatible. Unfortunately, it isn't. There's a [Gutenprint](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/) driver for this printer, but the documentation looked rather involved. I didn't have much time to dedicate to the task.

Can someone simplify the gutenprint setup process for me? Has anyone successfully used an 812c with SnowLeopard or Lion?

Comment: You may as well get them a new printer, they can be as cheep as $20.

Comment: That's something we are considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They decided to not bother trying to get Gutenprint to work; they bought a new printer.